# Same file upload twice in codeigniter

Tags: php, file, codeigniter

The below code snippet is built to upload multiple files into the folder.
    I don't know whats wrong in my code, the code is uploading file twice.
 [MUTIPLE FILE UPLOAD SNIPPET IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmw47.png)

Comment: Post your code as __text__

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that after all the trouble you went through with looping and iterating through the different files in the post, you're telling the `upload` library to always work on the same file

`$this->upload->do_upload('file')` means you're processing the upload on the `file` field on each loop. The name `file` in this case refers to the name of the `<input type="file"...>` field. This should change on each iteration to make reference to the next input field.